# Will the wearing of a silicone butt plug be detected by Security?

Tags: airport-security, uae, x-ray-machines, sex

I will be travelling from Asia to Europe with a stopover in UAE. I have four sex toys (discreet), none metal nor battery operated. I will put three in checked luggage (I don't expect any problems there based on my previous trips) but am planning to wear one (silicone butt plug) at the airport until boarding, which means it would go through Security check. (Maybe I will take it out in the lavatory inside the plane if I already feel uncomfortable.)

Will a worn silicone butt plug be detected?

I'm just thinking that the alarm would ring even though there is no metal in it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53523/discussion-on-question-by-jack99-will-the-wearing-of-a-silicone-butt-plug-be-det).

Answer (score 3):

Full body scanners image the (outside) *outline* of your body, going through (most) clothing. Depending on how much it adds to your outline, it can or cannot be detected; if it is relatively flat, they cannot see it.

Metal detectors will not find it for sure, as it has no metal (you claimed).

In a full body pat-down, they would not touch that area in detail, so again, they cannot find it.

I don't think there is any risk, unless you get their serious attention for *other reasons*, and they request you to go to a room for a full physical inspection, including body cavities. They would only do that if they have reason to believe you are smuggling goods in body cavity.
Even then, worst case, you will have to show it, and it might be an awkward situation, but they are not dangerous, so the 'other reasons' that got you there would be your concern.

Comment: No, but that was not the OP's question. So you think the whole answer is bad because of an off-topic half-sentence that was unconfirmed? I removed it.

Comment: Hi I'm sorry if my question is like that. It just so happen that the stopover is in UAE. Let's just say I change to a different stopover. I don't want to promote smuggling illegal items. Btw, thanks for editing my poorly constructed question :)